# Featurization for Relation Extraction using Support Vector Machine(SVM)

Tags: python, nlp

Regarding Relation Extraction using SVM paper(https://www.researchgate.net/publication/225671271_Relation_Extraction_Using_Support_Vector_Machine)I am looking for any code references on how to make features(word, pos, syntactic features, semantic feature types, chunk tags,distance) for relation extraction between two entities.
Entity1 - Drugs,
Entity2 - Disease,
Relation types:1.taking a drug caused disease
               2. Drug was taken for a disease,
first model is a binary classification model to classify if the entities are related to each other or not.
Second model takes only positive outputs from first model and classifies the relation which is a multi class classification model